# Sending Data from PHP to Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't understand how to explain my question, but I'm trying to say what I wanted to do.

I have created a modal to submit 'payment' for each person. I have created the list of person in a table with PHP loop, and a button against each person so that payment can be done by
clicking the button.
[image]

When I click on the button, a modal popup.
[image]
But how do i understand which person button is pressed. There is unique id for each person. Now, I have to sent the id from button click to my PHP code.
How can i do that?
Code for creating list of person:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sl++;
       echo "<tr><td>". $sl. "</td><td>". $row['name']. "</td><td>". $row['Total_Trip']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Pay']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Due']."</td><td>"."<button id='mbutton' onclick=btn()>Pay</button><button id='mbutton' onclick=btn()>Report</button>"."</td></tr>";
      }
```

HTML code for creating the Modal:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
     
     <h2>Pay to</h2>
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form action="test.php" method="POST">
      <label>Payment Amount</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="paymodal" placeholder="Amount"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="smitModal">
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript code for popup the modal:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

 function btn() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I need to sent the respective id & amount from modal code to my PHP code where payment will be processed.

Please help,

Comment: One advice I would like to give is that keep servers side code and client-side code different, don't mix them up. You could make an API call to your PHP file and get data from that API and render using javascript(or its any library). Now coming back to your question, where you are using this ``onclick=btn()``, pass parameters to this function, like ``onclick=btn(' " . $row['name']. " ')``   and in your javascript, you will get data regarding the use. You can save data in JavaScript ``Session`` and use it accordingly.

Comment: The key is to use the persons ID right from the start. For example, you can keep it as an html attribute like `'id="pay-button-'.$the_person_id.'"'` when you create the table and use it in the script to tell your backend which person was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "Pay" button, attach a function which gets the ID as a parameter. I assume `$sl` is the ID you mentioned.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sl++;
       echo "<tr><td>". $sl. "</td><td>". $row['name']. "</td><td>". $row['Total_Trip']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Pay']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Due']."</td><td>"."<button id='mbutton' onclick=btn(". $sl. ")>Pay</button><button id='mbutton' onclick=btn()>Report</button>"."</td></tr>";
      }
```

Then, by using the `btn()` function, Get the ID and add it to the HTML form by using below code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var formUserId = document.getElementById("userId");

 function btn(userId) {
  formUserId.value = userId;
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Then update your HTML Form to bind the UserId to that:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
     
     <h2>Pay to</h2>
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form action="test.php" method="POST">
      <label>Payment Amount</label><br>
      <input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId"><br>
      <input type="text" name="paymodal" placeholder="Amount"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="smitModal">
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```